# Wordpress show different custom post type

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, templates

In wordpress I want two different types of custom post. In one section I want to post all the `latest news` and in other I want to use as `blog`. In `latest news` post type when I will make a news it should display in the news section and in blog section when I will add a blog it should show in blog section. So can someone kindly tell me how to do that? Kindly remember that I have two different types of styles in the two different custom post in fronted. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? I am currently using wordpress twentytweleve theme.
Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You [register a post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) named "latest news", but you seem to already know that, so I am unsure what the question is. Do you want someone to copy and paste from the Codex for you, and change a couple of text strings?

```
function codex_custom_init_v2() {
    $args = array( 'public' => true, 'label' => 'Latest News' );
    register_post_type( 'latest-news', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init_v2' );
```

You can then customize the post type archive by creating an [`archive-{post_type}.php` file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display) and customize the single post display by creating a [`single-{post_type}.php` file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display).

Comment: what about the wordpress custom post type ui plugin?Do it still need to create the files for single-{post_type}.php and archive-{post_type}.php file?

Comment: I have no idea about the "custom post type ui plugin". You didn't ask about a plugin, and there are about 3 plugins I use regularly. That is not one of them. I'd guess you probably still have to create the "single" and "archive" files though.